# Mapping aggregate result as property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently facing a performance issue. I recently converted SQL queries to HQL, to simplify a lot of 1-1, 1-M joinings and now my aggregates functions (count, sum, avg) can only work as `@Formula`. The main issue of `@Formula` is a subselect per resulting row, many times I need between 10 and 600 resulting rows, giving total query times very long...

**HQL Query :**

```
select
    cp,
    count(cr) as ratingsCount,      // What I was using in SQL
    avr(cr.rate) as ratingsAverage  // What I was using in SQL
from Post cp
left join fetch cp.titles cmtt
left join fetch cp.contents cmtc
left join fetch cp.paths cmtp
left join fetch cp.categories
left join fetch cp.properties
left join fetch cp.userCreator
left join fetch cp.userUpdater
left join Rating r
    on r.keyPost = cp.keyPost
group by
    cp
```

**Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="common_posts")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable
{
    /* ... */

    public void setRatingsAverage(Double p_dRatingsAverage)
    {
        m_dRatingsAverage = p_dRatingsAverage;
    }

    // What I'm currently using...
    @Formula("(SELECT AVG(cr.rate) FROM common_ratings cr WHERE cr.keyPost = keyPost)")
    // What I've tested but doesn't work, was working in plain SQL
    //@Column(name = "ratingsAverage")
    // What I've also tested but doesn't work
    //@Formula("(ratingsAverage)")
    public Double getRatingsAverage()
    {
        return m_dRatingsAverage;
    }

    public void setRatingsCount(Integer p_iRatingsCount)
    {
        m_iRatingsCount = p_iRatingsCount;
    }

    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM common_ratings cr WHERE cr.keyPost = keyPost)")
    //@Column(name = "ratingsCount")
    public Integer getRatingsCount()
    {
        return m_iRatingsCount;
    }
}
```

I would like to have a solution without subqueries and without plain SQL.

Comment: Have you thought about using named queries, or `CriteriaQuery` ?

Comment: I never tried `CriteriaQuery` yet, neither named queries, I'll have to read about both. But could `CriteriaQuery` do more than HQL (in this situation)?

Comment: Well with `CriteriaQuery` you wouldn't need to use raw SQL queries.  This has the nice effect of not having to worry about injection and a few other things.

Comment: I was using SQL before, moving to HQL, but I was always using prepared statements with Hibernate no matter SQL or HQL.